# How do I link gui components to Unity web player?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, user-interface, unity-game-engine

So I created a scene in Unity and I want the user to be able to navigate through the scene with buttons and options from my web app framework, ASP .NET MVC 4. Right now, I'm not sure how to link the buttons and drop down menu selections to the Unity Web Player. Right now, for the drop down menu selections, the camera will move to a different view in the scene.

Are there any tutorials that I can read up on this or how to connect my drop down menu to the Unity web player?

Comment: Not a specific answer, but generally a Unity Web Player can interact with Javascript on the page used to display it, [as described in the manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/UnityWebPlayerandbrowsercommunication.html).